# The variable timeOld is being used without being initialized in c++

Tags: c++, char

```
char* timeNew = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(cpi->getTime());
if(timeFirst == true)
    {
    strcpy(timeOld,timeNew);
    timeFirst = false;
    }
```

how can I initiliase timeold if I dont know what the size of character array returned by cpi->getTime is?

Comment: `if(timeFirst == true)`? Ugh!

Comment: Prefer `if(timeFirst)`. The text `== true` is unnecessary and redundant. And redundant.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, and it's redundant too! You could just as well use `if ((timeFirst == true) == true)`

Comment: You've asked this question before! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769998/how-to-return-char-array-in-c

Comment: BTW: [How to: Convert Between Various (Microsoft) String Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory for it based on length of `timeNew`:

```
delete[] timeOld;
timeOld = new char[strlen(timeNew) + 1];
```

or you could make `timeOld` a `std::string` and let it manage memory for you:

```
std::string timeOld;

timeOld = timeNew; // If timeNew is dynamically allocated you must still
                   // delete[] it when no longer required, as timeOld
                   // takes a copy of timeNew, not ownership of timeNew.
```

You can access the `const char*` using `std::string::c_str()` if really required.

Answer (score 1):

Use strings where possible:

```
char *t= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(cpi->getTime());
std::string timeNew(t);
delete[] t;
if(timeFirst == true)
{
     timeOld=timeNew;
     timeFirst = false;
 }
```

if you don't have to manage the memory returned by teh function simply:

```
std::string timeNew(_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(cpi->getTime()));
if(timeFirst == true)
{
     timeOld=timeNew;
     timeFirst = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use ConvertBSTRToString then use `boost::scoped_array<char>` or `boost::shared_array<char>` to ensure you get clean-up.

```
boost::shared_array<char> time;
time.reset( _com_util::ConvertBSTRtoString( cpi->getTime() );
```

automatically reallocates. No calls to delete or delete[] necessary.