# I have a local char array in a function — when I return the array name, why is the return value null?

Tags: c++

I have come across a very confusing thing. I have made a local char array in a function, and return the array name, but the return value is null?

```
char* get_string(){
    char local[] ="hello world\n";
    cout<<"1"<<(int)local<<endl;//shows a reasonable value
    return local;
}

int main(){
    char* p = get_string();
    cout<<"2"<<(int) p<<endl;//shows 0
    return 0;
}
```

I know it is not good to use a local variable, because when the function returns, the stack part that the local variable occupies would be used by other function calls, but I think this should return the address of the first element of the array, should not be null. I'm very confused; any help would be appreciated.

I use QT 32 version, compiler is MSVC2015 (I am at baby stage about compiler; not even sure that MSVC is compiler name).

--updated, I think this question is not a duplicate of this [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c,as) I know it is not valid to use atomic/local storage outside the scope, and my question is why the return value becomes 0 despite its inappropriate use.

--ok, thank you, everyone. I think I found the answer.  I see the assembly code of the function `char* get_string()`, the last part of the assembly code is this

```
0x44bce7  mov $0x0,%eax 
0x44bcec     leave
0x44bced     ret
```

I think this is implementation defined, hard coded in the compiler, if I return the address of a local variable, then `%eax` or `%rax` is set to 0.

Comment: @wangz The code has undefined behavior because the array is not alive after exiting the function.

Comment: Let this be a lesson that "undefined behaviour" means *anything can happen*. It does not mean "oh probably the stack bla bla this and that etc."

Comment: Undefined behavior is like that - undefined and hard to predict. If I had to guess, I'd say compiler sees that you are returning an address of local variable and substitutes it with nullptr to allow the calling code to catch this error.

Comment: First of all pointer may not fit in `int`, second there is nothing to help with, your expectation is simply wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is returning address of local variable UB? Could you point out the standard rule for me? My UB sanitiser doesn't catch that.

Comment: @eerorika I was wrong. I though he outputs the string itself. The problem is that he uses casting to int.;)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's a problem (makes the program ill-formed), but the result reproduces even when casting to `void*` (in GCC; not reproduced in Clang; I didn't test MSVC).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c) or [how to return a local array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769998/how-to-return-local-array-in-c)

Comment: @eerorika Returning the address is not UB. Using the result is UB.

Comment: Your compiler is likely gcc, not msvc

Comment: @n.m. Using is implementation defined. Except indirecting through the pointer, which is UB.

Comment: @eerorika since implqementations don't bother to document their implementation-defined behaviour, the distinction is not that meaningful.

Comment: @n.m. Distinction is still meaningful, since UB has way wider ramifications. Implementation may assume that there is no UB, and optimise accordingly. Implementation may not assume that there is no implementation defined behaviour. Implementation defined sans the definition is same as unspecified behaviour as far as I can tell.

Comment: @eerorika An implementation may define any implementation-defined behaviour as filling all variables with random bit patterns. Since they don't bother to document, I might just as well assume the actually do. Unspecified behaviour actually specifies a fixed set of possible behaviours ("it is unspecified whether X or Y") so it is not at all the same.

Comment: @n.m. Sure. That's a good idea. But there should be no need to plan for your escape path in case of nasal demons.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you're wrong, most of implementations have a document that regulates certain things.  Most of what considered implementation defined goes to ABI spec, some actually might be defined by standards applied to OS\platform, etc.

Comment: @Swift Can you find how and where "any use of an invalid pointer other than to perform indirection or deallocate", which is an implementation-defined behaviour, is actually defined by gcc or any other popular implementation?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns'  Firstly, that's an UB, not an implementation-defined behavior. Second, ABI specification I mentioned are separate of compiler and are architecture or  OS-wide (regardless compiler usually, though in past we had cases when different compilers were creating incompatible binaries). Thirdly, gcc is not a single compiler, it's a collection. There are several hundreds of implementations, for each platform and architecture. Care to specify which?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I have quoted a sentence from the standard verbatim. You can see the full paragraph in the accepted answer. If you think it is wrong, you should author a defect report. Regarding gcc based implementations, select any one you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard says (quoting the latest draft):

> [basic.stc]
>
> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values.
> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
> **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.**

`p` contains an invalid pointer value, and printing the value of the pointer is included in "any other use", and thus the behaviour is implementation defined. In the observed case, the behaviour was to output 0.

Note to readers that in the code in the example there is no indirection through the invalid pointer and the behaviour is not undefined.

---

P.S. Converting pointer to `int` is not correct. `int` isn't guaranteed to be sufficiently large to represent all pointer values, and on most 64 bit systems, it isn't sufficiently large. Standard only specifies the behaviour for conversion to sufficiently large integer type. I would suggest converting to `void*` instead for this case.

Comment: thank you , I inspect the assembly code , and see before return from function, the %eax is set to 0 .And I think this is implementation defined ,and your opinion that int may not be big enough to hold pointer , in this case ,it is ok ,as I know I will compile it to 32 bit code , but use void* and print it out as hex is better

Comment: @wangz In case you want to convert pointer to integer, use `std::intptr_t`.