# How do I transfer const char* from function to function?

Tags: c++, string

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* f;
const char* getstring()
{
    f = fopen ("hello.txt", "r");
    char x[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) x[i] = 0;
    for (int c = getc(f), i = 0; (c != EOF) && (i < 200); c = getc(f), i++)
        x[i] = c;
    fclose(f);
    printf ("getstring(): x = %s", x);
    const char* y = x;
    printf ("getstring(): y = %s", y);
    return y;
}

void printstring (const char* string)
{
    printf ("%s", string);
}

int main()
{
    printstring(getstring());
    printf ("\nprintf: %s", getstring());
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
getstring(): x = Hello World
getstring(): y = Hello World
���getstring(): x = Hello World
getstring(): y = Hello World

printf: ��������
```

I don't know why the `printstring()` function is outputting nothing and `printf` is outputting random data or why there is a bit of random data at the end of the `string` when I use the `printstring()` function.

Is there any way to fix this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! We highly suggest that you leave plain old C `char*` strings and use `std::string`. It's C++ standard library and has lots of benefits. Unless you're using `C` and not `C++` of course

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? I'm surprised that it teaches C-style strings.

Comment: @snoopy Yeah. I automatically default to using c instead of c++ because I'm not very familiar with the functions in the c++ standard libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769998/how-to-return-local-array-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that `getstring()` returns a pointer to a local array.  This array gets destructed when the function returns, so you have an dangling pointer.  Using this pointer is then undefined behavior.  Anything can happen: for example you can get garbage random value, you can get the old unchanged value, or the system could crash.

### The solution

Since this question is labelled c++, just use `std::string` instead of `char*`, and this kind of nightmare will vanish for good.

Note that Using `std::string` in `prinf()` would require you get a pointer with  `.c_str()`.

If for an obscure reason, you are required to use `char*` you'd have to to use `strdup()` or llocate some memory for the c string and return a pointner to that memory.  But the caller must then delete this pointer if you don't want memory to leak.

Comment: Accessing it can also blow up. Or reverse time.

Comment: If I return the local array, I get ```(null)``` for some reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes ! I just added that.  About reversing time I'm more skeptical as I am still working on my time machine ;-)

Comment: @Fract Pointer to local array is invalid outside the local scope. The value of an invalid pointer is unspecified.

Comment: @Christophe [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) Harnessing that for actual time-travel is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @eerorika How should I return the string in the local array?

Comment: @Fract Return a `std::string` object

Comment: @eerorika yes, I was typing that while the 4 comments were posted: string if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The C string is stored in a function local char array. This array is destroyed when the function is left. Since the question is tagged as C++ use std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string getstring()
{
    std::ifstream f("hello.txt");
    std::string x;
    x.resize(200);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) x[i] = 0;
    for (int c = f.get(), i = 0; (c != EOF) && (i < 200); c = f.get(), i++)
        x[i] = c;
    std::cout << "getstring(): x = " << x;
    const std::string& y = x;
    std::cout << "getstring(): y = " << y;
    return x;
}

void printstring (const std::string& string)
{
    std::cout << string;
}

int main()
{
    printstring(getstring());
    std::cout << "\nprintf: " << getstring();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since others have explained **how** to go about resolving the issue, I'll expand the other answers a bit and explain **why** you had an issue in the first place.

To put it simply, whenever a function is called, it is given a *stack frame* (also called *activation record*) of its own. That is to say: it is given an area of memory where it can place its local variables. When the function returns, the stack frame is destroyed. If you then call another function, the stack frame of that function overwrites the stack frame of the previous function.

In this specific case, when `getstring` returns and `printstring` and subsequently `printf` are called, the stack frames of the latter two along with that of `main` overwrite the data that was previously located within the stack frame of `getstring`. The most likely result is that `printf` will output complete junk. In the worst case, it can make the entire program crash if the null terminator of the string was overwritten.

It is also interesting to note that in your case it seems that a binary value corresponding with that of the null terminator `\0` was inserted somewhere, because only a bit of junk is printed before `printf` returns. This would indicate that it did not stop at the original null terminator of the character array `x` but rather encountered a value it interpreted as the null terminator and returned.

If you wish, you can read more about the call stack [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for C code (not C++).  In the code in [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe)'s answer on the similar question that I found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769998/how-to-return-local-array-in-c), which I didn't find before I posted this question, I found the `malloc(bytes)` function does the trick but if you compile with `gcc`, you have to have to convert the malloc function as a char* manually by using `(char*) malloc (bytes)`.  I also found that because it's using pointers you will have to treat the allocated string as a global variable when you `free()` it.
Here is an example of the working code based on the code in my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE* f;
char* getstring()
    {
    f = fopen ("hello.txt", "r");
    char* x = (char*) malloc (200);
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) x[i] = 0;
    for (int c = getc(f), i = 0; (c != EOF) && (i < 200); c = getc(f), i++)
        { x[i] = c; length++; }
    fclose(f);
    return x;
    }

void printstring (char* string)
    {
    printf ("%s", string);
    free (string);
    }

int main()
    {
    printstring(getstring());
    return 0;
    }
```

And this outputs the exact first 200 bytes of "hello.txt".